# Convert length-one character to one-byte string

Tags: string, r, escaping, byte

OK, I admit that the title is a bit misleading. I'm braindead currently, so I may be missing something obvious here.

I'm working on R-powered webapp, and I'd like to pass certain parameters to `read.table` function - `sep` among others. Everything works like a charm if I'm passing single-byte characters as `sep` argument: `,`, `;`, `|`... but if I try to pass `\t`, I get an error:

```
invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte
```

of course, this happens because `\t` is actually escaped (`\\t`). Is there any chance that I can escape escapes, and pass it "as is" - i.e. a single byte string?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to do this? I'm not very familiar with R, but there must be a way to write a literal tab character (probably written as `\t`) in your code; I'm not sure why it would be double-escaped as `\\t`...

Comment: It's `R` convention - http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-does-backslash-behave-strangely-inside-strings_003f

Comment: that looks like what I'd expect... so why can't you just use `"\t"`? That would be an actual tab character, whereas `"\\t"` is a literal "backslash T".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write `sep="\t"` as the parameter to `read.table`.

In the case of a tab, it is the `t` that gets escaped.  In other words, you are telling R that `t` doesn't really mean `t`, but `tab`.  If you escape the `\`, by using `\\` then you are telling R that the `\` doesn't really mean `escape` but a literal `\`.

Here is some code illustrating the correct usage of `sep="\t"` in `read.table`.  And just for the fun of it, I use `textConnection` to use a connection to write to and read from, rather than using a file on disk:

```
# Create a tab delimited file
zz <- textConnection("foo", "w")
write.table(matrix(1:12, ncol=3), file=zz, sep="\t")
close(zz)
foo

# The simple way:
tabsep <- "\t"

# The hard way, or if data was passed from a web app and you need to clean it
tabsep <- gsub("\\\\t", "\t", "\\t")


# Read a tab delimited file
zz <- textConnection(foo)
read.table(zz, sep=tabsep)
close(zz)
```

This produces the following output:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  5  9
2  2  6 10
3  3  7 11
4  4  8 12
```

Comment: Thanks Andrie, but I already knew that! =( If you define separator as a length-one character: `sep <- "\t"`, and then you do: `read.table("somedata.txt", sep = sep)` you'll get the error. Is there any chance that I can convert `sep` argument to single-byte and pass it in `read.table` formals?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  (I have edited my answer to do what you asked - this works fine on my machine.)

Comment: It looks odd... and it's probably one of those "get some sleep" mistakes. Will inspect that more thoroughly... Thanks for reply!

Comment: OK, so, is there any chance that I can convert `"\\t"` to `"\t"`? (why haven't I put it in this manner right from the start?)